# Why is the FOV of the Synthetic Vision of the Prodigy Flight Deck asymmetric?

Tags: avionics, synthetic-vision

Why is the FOV of the Synthetic Vision of the Prodigy Flight Deck asymmetric?

I am just reading through the [manual of the Prodigy® Flight Deck 100](http://static.garmincdn.com/pumac/190-00728-04_0A_Web.pdf) and came to the chapter about the synthetic vision. The document states:

> [...] The field of view is 30 degrees to the left and 35 degrees to the right. [...]

[Source (Page 510)](http://static.garmincdn.com/pumac/190-00728-04_0A_Web.pdf)

- What is the reason and what are the advantages of having such a FOV with 30° to the left and 35° to the right?

Comment: Can you summarize the portion of the manual related to this feature instead of sending people to the 688 pages document?

Comment: Just a quick guess, but perhaps it reflects the field of view of a pilot in the left seat.

Comment: Seems to be that the PFD center is [not at the center of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xizc4.png), leaving more space on the right, hence the resulting dissymmetry.

Answer (score 3):

According to the FAA's [AC 25-11B](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_25-11B.pdf), there is no requirement for the asymmetrical SVS field-of-view.

It's not a feature either, as in there is no benefit. Whereas an [Enhanced Vision System](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33377) (EVS) system benefits from an offset overlay to match the sensor's deviation to the different flight deck seat positions.

---

With that said, here's my *guess* on why it sees 5° more on the right side.

From the FAA AC linked above:

> The display can depict the scene from the pilot’s view looking through the front window (egocentric) or from outside the aircraft (exocentric). However, if implemented on a primary display, then the display must depict the scene from the pilot’s perspective looking through the front window.

This means the SVS is egocentric, which leads me to conclude* that the left seat is more-or-less aligned with the attitude indicator's centerline. But because of the display's size, the attitude indicator itself is off center, resulting in the bigger angle (5° in this case) to the right.

Which would explain the equal distances shown in white below. They could have been adjusted to allow a centered attitude indicator with the altitude tape being wider than the speed tape.

[image]
([Source](http://static.garmincdn.com/pumac/190-00728-04_0A_Web.pdf); added arrows)

* My conclusion is based on the assumption they would want the SVS graphics to share the center of rotation of the attitude indicator. This poses a question with regard to the right seat, because as I can see from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoFed.jpg), the seating position is not accounted for (unlike with EVS).

But since SVS is not meant for [barnstorming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkGZa.jpg), I just might be overthinking it. Also, SVS does not need to show everything:

> SV depictions on the PFD have the potential to provide pilots with enhanced terrain and landmark awareness during non-precision and precision approaches. However, the display may not provide depth perception and may not provide a field-of-view for pilots to know what is to the left and right of the display view area.